Tabulator with Vue and Selectable Cell Range with Clipboard breaks after calling setData
I'm trying to set up a tabulator table with Vue and Selectable Cell Range with Clipboard based on this example from Tabulator and these Vue Integration docs from Tabulator
The problem is, after calling setData, pasting the selectable range no longer works and the console warns No bounds defined on Range
I can confirm this is not an issue with tabulator, but only an issue when integrating with Vue.
Here is a working JSFiddle without Vue integration.
Here is the broken JSFiddle that is nearly identical, with Vue integration.
This is the relevant code from the broken JSFiddle.
<div id="app">
  <button @click="onSetData">Set Data</button>
  <div ref="table"></div>
</div>

<script type="module">
  import { createApp } from 'vue'
  var tableData = [
    {name:"Bob", "quantity":1},
    {name:"Steve", "quantity":''},
    {name:"Jim", "quantity":''},
  ]

  var otherTableData = [
    {name:"Bob", "quantity":4},
    {name:"Steve", "quantity":5},
    {name:"Jim", "quantity":6},
  ]

  createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        tabulator: null,
        tableData: tableData
      }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.tabulator = new Tabulator(this.$refs.table, {
        data: this.tableData, //link data to table
        reactiveData:true, //enable data reactivity
        columns: [
          {title:"Name", field:"name", width:100, editor:"input"},
          {title:"Quantity", field:"quantity", width:100, editor:"input"}
        ], //define table columns
        //enable range selection
        selectableRange:1,
        selectableRangeColumns:true,
        selectableRangeRows:true,
        selectableRangeClearCells:true,

        //change edit trigger mode to make cell navigation smoother
        editTriggerEvent:"dblclick",

        //configure clipboard to allow copy and paste of range format data
        clipboard:true,
        clipboardCopyStyled:false,
        clipboardCopyConfig:{
            rowHeaders:false,
            columnHeaders:false,
        },
        clipboardCopyRowRange:"range",
        clipboardPasteParser:"range",
        clipboardPasteAction:"range",

        rowHeader:{resizable: false, frozen: true, width:40, hozAlign:"center", formatter: "rownum", cssClass:"range-header-col", editor:false},

        //setup cells to work as a spreadsheet
        columnDefaults:{
            headerSort:false,
            headerHozAlign:"center",
            editor:"input",
            resizable:"header",
            width:100,
        },
      })
    },
    methods: {
        onSetData() {
        console.log('Set table data!')
        this.tabulator.setData(otherTableData)
      }
    },

  }).mount('#app')
</script>

My current workaround is to use this.tabulator.updateData with an index (updateData docs) This preserves the copy/paste functionality. But I would prefer to use setData
Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!
